# How to tell a method to use the default value of its optional parameter?

Tags: c#, default-value, optional-parameters

Consider the following method

```
private void PrintThis(string xxx, string text = "MARY")
        {
            Trace(text); // MARY
        }
```

and assuming I use it as such:

```
PrintThis(xxx:"whatever", text: (string)myArray.ElementAtOrDefault(index: 5) ?? default)
```

then if the myArray is outside of bounds at index 5 `(string)myArray.ElementAtOrDefault(index: 5) ?? default` becomes the default value of string (an empty string).

Assuming there is a way, how could I make it so that if `(string)myArray.ElementAtOrDefault(index: 5)` returns `null` then the default value of the optional parameter is used (`"MARY"` in this case) without modifying the method to check if the parameter is the default value and then assign `"MARY"` to it (like `if(text ==default)text="MARY"`)?

Comment: The usual approach is to give the parameter the *actual* default of its type (that is, `string text = default`, which is the same as `string text = null`) and then use `??` in the method itself to produce the "filled" default (`Trace(text ?? "MARY")`). Using a trivial `default` tends to lead to less surprises down the road anyway, since the compiler actually interpolates the value at the call site, which can lead to unexpected effects if the default is changed without all code being recompiled.

Comment: If changing the method to use a `null` default is truly not acceptable, your only recourse is to actually change the call. That is, do `var element = myArray.ElementAtOrDefault(index: 5); if (element is null) PrintThis("whatever") else PrintThis("whatever", element)`. Of course this just trades one kind of duplication for another.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I see, thank you for the helpful insight. So in the end there's no C# feature that allows me to do what I want in a more elegant way. I am using an array with a lot of elements which I then cast and I didn't want to write the call to the method multiple times. If you could turn this into an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the default values in the target method.

```
private void PrintThis(string xxx, string text = default)
{
    Trace(text ?? "MARY");
}
```

And the callers need not worry about the default value:

```
PrintThis(xxx:"whatever", text: (string)myArray.ElementAtOrDefault(index: 5))
```

Comment: You might've read the answer before I made edits to it, but I updated it and asked if there's a way to get the value of the default parameter without making changes to the method.